# Normalize database table "tags"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called **tags** with columns `id`, `vid_id`, `name` where id is a random id generated with `md5(uniqid());` vid_id is the id of the video that tag is associated with, and name is the tag name. If a video has 5 tags, they all get stored in the tags table. I realized lately this is a bad table design because I have many duplicate tags. I created another table **tag_map**. It has three columns `id`, `vid_id`, `tag_id`. I want to basically implement the 'toxi' solution shown here http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html.

What I want to do is somehow transfer the data over from **tags** to **tag_map**, delete the vid_id column in **tags** and delete any extra entries in tags so each tag_map entry is mapped to only one tag entry. Anyone know an efficient way to do this? I keep thinking:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tags';
$stmt3 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt3->execute();
while ($row = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

$id=md5(uniqid());

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tag_map VALUES (?,?,?)';
$insert = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$insert->execute(array($id,$row['vid_id'],$row['id']));
}
```

but then I get confused when I try to think of how I am going to remove the extra tags in table **tags** and map each tag_map entry to only one tags entry. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your post, then what you're after is a "Junction table" or "join table."  (Upon re-reading, yes, this is the "Toxi" solution you're referring to.  Not sure where it got the name "Toxi" but whatever.)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

You want to have a table that has exactly one row for a given video.  And another table that has exactly one row for each tag.  Then you need a third table in between that has one row for every combination of video and tag.  That way, you can query the third join table for all of the videos that match a given tag, or all the tags that match a given video.

I would create a new table "tag" and a table "video_tag".

```
foreach ( video_record in the video table ) {
    existingTags = read in list of tags for video_record from existing_tags_table
    foreach ( tag in existingTags ) {
        newTag = read tag from new tag table
        if ( newTag == null ) {
            save tag in new table
            newTag.name = existing tag name
            newTag.id = id from save procedure above
        }
        save entry in video_tag( video.id, newTag.id )
    }
}
```

Then delete the old tag table.  If you want, do some renaming of the new tag tables.

Comment: I have a join table. That table is tag_map, it joins table tags and table videos. The issue I have is I didn't have the join table before so I have all these entries in tags. I have to some how organize the data I currently have in tags, and redistribute it into tag_map so the structure will function properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me Marvo!

Comment: Made a tweak to point out that when you read in existingTags, you're reading them in for the video record you just read in.  Hope that mistake didn't hold you up.  (Of course, your old model had the video ID right there in the tag table, so you probably figured it out.)  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is set the `vid_id` and `tag_id` pair as the primary key in your new `tag_map` table. That way, when you go through the algorithm you have listed above, duplicate map entries will not be created, but you'll still have one for each tag. Then, you can run a query to delete duplicates in the `tags` table like this one:

```
DELETE FROM TAGS WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT tag_id FROM TAG_MAP)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but that wouldn't work man. The vid_id and tag_id are not unique in the table tag_map. There could be many entries for the same video and tag_id can be used to map different videos to the same tag.

Comment: I guess what I was trying to say is that the (vid_id, tag_id) pair should be the primary key of your tag_map table. That way, you could still have the same tag_id map to different vid_ids, but it wouldn't allow duplicate entries to be inserted during your normalization. I'm doing something similar on a project of my own. I'm probably missing something here :)